# Memcached to be or not to be? (c++)

Tags: c++, database, caching, architecture, memcached

I have a 3 tiers structure as followed.
A(web Server)--> B(BizLib) --> C (DB Server)

I want to use memcached connected to the end of my B server, but I'm a bit hesitate as it goes through network too so the latency decrease isn't that obvious.

My plan is to pre-store some frequently used data as Map from DB Server into BizLib.

If my B Server is a Thrift Server running, and there are a lot of using accessing my BizLiz, but how can different users use my same set of pre-stored data in BizLib memory at B? Can I make that "cache class" as singleton so everyone will share the same values?

What if the data Map grow too big, will it just crash or it is just not efficient to do so?

Please advise as I'm a newbie in designing architecture.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do any caching inside of BizLib, keep that one simple.

Memcached handles all the tasks which you are worrying about internally, specifically storing items in a map, managing eviction of unused cache entries, and even distributing the map onto multiple physical servers, should it exceed the local memory.

Access the MemcacheD server (respectively the server pool) straight away from the web application, don't go the detour via server B.

Whenever your web application can not find a set of data in MemcacheD, have it pass down the request all the way to the database, and have the web application store the result in MemcacheD.

Neither try to cache anything, nor limit yourself to caching only database requests. MemcacheD is also great at caching entire HTML fragments since these can turn out to be quite expensive to generate as well and just caching these instead of intermediate aggregations is quite simple.

Make sure to profile you application thoroughly before adding a cache in a certain location. Also make sure not to mix user specific views and generic data as long as it can be avoided, as this means that you can no longer reuse this data for other users from the point on where it has been merged, this has to be ensured when designing the interface between the web application and BizLib.

By avoiding the detour via B, you can take unnecessary load of the one part of application which is the most difficult to scale, whereby you can easily add in additional web application servers and more MemcacheD instances. You also gain the advantage of possibly even being able to serve some requests without B and C getting involved at all.

For starters, you can even have the MemcacheD running on the same physical machine as the web application - as the web application is most likely going to be heavy on the CPU, while MemcacheD solely needs RAM. That way, you can avoid network latency altogether, even though this only applies as long as there is only one web server.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to cache at multiple layers.  You are caching both in your data map, and in memcached, and (likely) at the database layer.

This is probably too much.  Especially if you are looking at putting memcached in a separate machine.

Make sure you don't introduce cache too early.  Find out what is actually going to perform slowly before you introduce cache architecture.

See if your database lookup *actually* takes longer than it should.  Most DBMS servers have a cache for often-loaded tables and indices.

If you decide you do want to cache, don't cache both in memcached and your BizLib.  I'd personally put in in memcached that is running locally with your BizLib.  This eliminates the network latency, but you still get the advantage of explicitly sizing your cache, and taking advantage of the LRU algorithms, etc.

If you later decide that sharing your cache across multiple instances of your BizLib would benefit more than eliminating the network latency, you can always consolidate out (or even federate your cache).